# AutoSKU and Commerce Kickstart 2.0 or Commerce backoffice

Tags: commerce

I would like to use the AutoSKU module with the functionality provided by commerce backoffice.  Right now what I have done is installed the module commerce_backoffice with my commerce module which is the functionality from Commerce Kickstart 2.0 from my understanding.

I then installed the AutoSKU module.  However, since the software design has changed there are no longer product types, there are product variation types.  It doesn't seem that AutoSKU works with the new functionality.

Has anyone ported AutoSKU to work with Commerce Kickstart 2.0?

Answer (score 0):

The AutoSKU that works with product variations is part of Commerce Kickstart 2.0.  You will have to enable the module of AutoSKU once you have installed Commerce Kickstart 2.0.